# how to display fixed dropdown in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to display priority information in a drop down. Currently i am using a integer field to store the priority, but i would like to display high/medium/low instead of letting user type in a priority.

A way to approximate this is to use a Priority database which stores 3 elements, 1:high, 2:medium, 3:low, but it seems like an overkill.

Any easier way would be much appreciated!

Jason

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify choices for a field http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/choices/.

```
PRIORITY_CHOICES = ((1, 'High'),
                    (2, 'Medium'),
                    (3, 'Low'))

class MyModel(models.Model):
    priority = models.IntegerField(choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could write your model like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Priority(models.Model):
    PRIORITY_LOW = 3
    PRIORITY_MEDIUM = 2
    PRIORITY_HIGH = 1

    PRIORITY_CHOICES = (
        (PRIORITY_LOW, 'low'),
        (PRIORITY_MEDIUM, 'medium'),
        (PRIORITY_HIGH, 'high'),
    )

    priority = models.IntegerField(choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES)
```

You read more from the [documentation](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/choices/)

Comment: You have mixed up the order of value / Text for the choices, it should be eg. (PRIORITY_LOW, 'low')

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! Though the order is wrong for what i need, eg. 'low' and PRIORITY_LOW need to be exchanged to print out low in the drop down menu

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've mixed up the values. I've updated them with the correct values.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add choices to the model element

So:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    mydata = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices= ((u'H', u'High',), (u'M', u'Medium'), (u'L', u'Low')))
```

Would store H,M,L in the DB, but present High, Medium, Low.  Admin defaults fields with the choices attribute to a drop down selector

Comment: I'd say assigning the priorites to integers rather than to characters makes probably more sense, as you can then order your objects more easily by priority in a queryset (if that's needed somewhere).